# Interchange of Position of Two Keyword Arguments Throws Error

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have an odd problem. I know that in Python, kwargs follow args, so I checked for that and it's not the problem. What is the problem is this:

Fine:

`def __init__(self, sample_rate, label=u"", data=[] ):`

TypeError: `__init__()` got multiple values for keyword argument 'data':

`def __init__(self, sample_rate,  data=[], label=u""):`

The calling line that throws the error looks like this:

```
def __getslice__(self, start, stop):
    return Channel(self.sample_rate, self.label, data=list.__getslice__(self,start,stop))
```

The full code:

```
class Channel(list):
  sample_rate = 0

  def __init__(self, sample_rate, data=[], label=u"" ):
     list.__init__(self,data)
     self.sample_rate = sample_rate
     self.label = label

  @property
  def nyquist_rate(self):
      return float(self.sample_rate) / 2.0

  def __getslice__(self, start, stop):
      return Channel(self.sample_rate, self.label, data=list.__getslice__(self,start,stop))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second version (`def __init__(self, sample_rate, data=[], label=u""):`), the second positional argument (when called, that means not counting `self`) is `data`, but in `__getslice__`, the second argument that you pass is `label`. So you should either keep label as the second argument, or change the function call to this:

```
return Channel(self.sample_rate, label=self.label, data=list.__getslice__(self,start,stop))
```

Comment: Bah! A prime example of why I shouldn't code at 4 in the morning. Thank you all for bothering to catch my dumb errors.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the code with

```
Channel(self.sample_rate, self.label, data=list.__getslice__(self,start,stop))
```

Note that the second parameter has no keyword, so the interpreter assumes this is the `data` parameter (because that's the order they are defined in the function). If you add `label=` it should solve it.

**But, you have a more important error in your code:** Never use [] as a default value. The reason is this code is evaluated at function definition time. every time you call this code with no `data` parameter, **you'll get the same list as a default value**. and it might not be empty after the first time! This is true for all mutable datatypes. The correct way to do this, is to use `None` as a default value and inside the function (code that runs each time) init a new [], if the parameter value is None.
(This gocha is also explained well by David Goodger, in [Default Parameter Values](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#default-parameter-values))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your calling code, you have two positional arguments:

```
return Channel(self.sample_rate, self.label, data=list.__getslice__(self,start,stop))
#              sample_rate (pos) data (pos)  data (kw)
```

In Python 2.x, there is no distinction between positional and keyword arguments **in the function definition**. When a function is called, positional arguments from the function invocation are used to fill arguments left to right, then all keyword arguments are bound. In your case, `data` is bound both by a positional and a keyword arguments. It works in the other case because then the second positional argument is used for `label`, and `data` only gets the keyword argument.